# Please help me edit my .htaccess to allow hyphens in the urls

Tags: php, variables

### Update

In my original post I seem to have implied my variable name has a hyphen. My issue seems to be with the htaccess file below not matching on a hyphen but my $_GET variable content has a hyphen, not the variable itself.

### original

I originally referenced http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php which a user stated it is not possible to reference a php variable (by $_POST or $_GET) with a hyphen but this was written in 2009.

In one of my URL's, I allow users to enter a unique ID as "www.site.com/id123" which the "id123" is picked up as a $_GET variable with php. Some users have chosen to use "www.site.com/id-123" which does not work (no server error other than page cannot be found).

Any ideas on this?

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

#if file or directory do not exist, try as an unique id
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index?ID=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Thinking through more, the rewrite rule above seems it may need modification to handle a hyphen request. Does this seem right?

Comment: You should show some code... But you should be able to reference it using `$_GET["id-123"]` anyway I think. Do a `print_r($_GET)` to see what happens

Comment: I have never used variable variables, and never had a need for them. I think they are not a good practice, it's harder to keep track of the code's logic. Instead, why no use arrays with string keys?

Comment: @briedis - it is not a variable variable. The content of the $_GET variable has a hyphen. I apologize if I was confusing

Comment: As said it's the regex. Update the RewriteRule to `^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)$` to allow the hyphen.

Comment: @mario - your code and tom's below differs but his does seem to work - any reason your's is different?

Comment: @JM4: The backslash isn't required for a hyphen found at the _end_ of a character class.

Comment: No, that's just the non-expert version. You wouldn't need the \ right in front of the `-` in this very constellation. It's just a case of better safe than sorry. (in case you extend it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` file needs modifying to support hyphens.

Change

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index?ID=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ index?ID=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 5):

A string's contents may contain a hyphen. A variable's name may not.

It's not clear in your question where the HTTP querystring comes into it. `$_GET['some-variable']` is fine, as the array key is a string. `$my-var` is not fine.

If your page requests aren't working, it's far more likely to be a problem with your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Tomalak - thanks for the help. Using any name (without hyphen) works fine so I am not sure it is entirely the cause but certainly could be. The variable name in this case does not contain a hyphen, it is the variable content. I will post the code to my htaccess file for reference

Comment: @JM4: You haven't shown us what the link is, if any, between the URL and a PHP variable name. This is a huge schism running down the centre of your question.

Comment: @Tomalak - yes I have, it is in the htaccess file above, $1 represents any content after said url so $1 in the example above is: "id-123"

Comment: @JM4: Yes; you have edited your question now. :) See my other answer.

Comment: @ColShrapnel: Why don't you take **one minute** off being an ass, leaving these abusive comments, and actually describe why you think we "can't read". In case you hadn't noticed, the guy has edited his question several times.

Comment: easy fellas - all in good fun. Thanks to everybody for your help

Answer (score 1):

no, it is not possible

variable names start with a letter or underscore, optionally followed by a number, a letter or an underscore.
<sup>http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php</sup>

For an associative array key, you can use any string; since strings are allowed to include a hyphen, you could use `$_GET['user-id'];`.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, [you cannot](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Variable names follow the same rules
>   as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   variable name starts with a letter or
>   underscore, followed by any number of
>   letters, numbers, or underscores.

In practice, well...

```
<?php

${'widh-hyphen'} = 'This variable has a pyphen';
${'Variable with funny name. Woot!'} = 'And this is even worse!';
var_dump(${'widh-hyphen'}, ${'Variable with funny name. Woot!'});

?>
```

... prints:

```
string(26) "This variable has a pyphen"
string(23) "And this is even worse!"
```

So I'd say you can.

Nothing of this should apply to GET and POST input data, though. Since [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) should always be disabled, your parameter become keys of the `$_GET` and `$_POST` associative arrays, and [other rules apply](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> A key may be either an integer or a
>   string. If a key is the standard
>   representation of an integer, it will
>   be interpreted as such (i.e. "8" will
>   be interpreted as 8, while "08" will
>   be interpreted as "08"). Floats in key
>   are truncated to integer. The indexed
>   and associative array types are the
>   same type in PHP, which can both
>   contain integer and string indices.

In such case, you must only take into account that [dots are converted to underscores](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) for historical reasons:

> Dots and spaces in variable names are
>   converted to underscores. For example
>    becomes
>   $_REQUEST["a_b"].

Answer (score 0):

As Tom says, you're allowed hyphens in strings, so $_GET[user] = 'id-123' won't give you any problems, nor will sending any data like get.php?user=id-123.

I assume your .htaccess will rewrite www.site.com//id-123 to /getuser.php?user=id-123
If so, you shouldn't have problems.

But if you're trying, for some reason to create $id-123 then you will have some issues..

Comment: i believe it is in the .htaccess file as he suggests in the rewrite rule specifications. Posted above

Answer (score 0):

One *could* use the alternative syntax for quirky variable names:

```
${'my-var'} = 123;
```

But as the other answers said, that's wholly irrelevant for your case. You don't need it. Since you receive the data as value you wouldn't even need to honor the $_GET variable name transformation.

The problem in your case (page not found) sounds like a `RewriteRule` issue. Check that it does contain the hyphen in its regex:

```
RewriteRule  ^([\w+\-]+)$  get.php?id=$1

                #  ^^  missing
```

Comment: i think you are correct. The rewrite rule you mention stil seems to miss the target but I agree a hyphen is needed in the regex

Comment: @JM4: Left you the appropriate regex as comment atop, after you posted the source.

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes, variables can have whatever name you want. You only have to access them in another way.

This works:

```
$foo = "id-123"; 
$$foo = "hello";
var_dump($$ffoo);
```

You can check this by adding `var_dump($GLOBALS);` which will show a variable named "id-123".

You can not, however, access such a variable the normal way: `var_dump($id-123);` won't work.

However, since you are talking about GET/POST variables: These are only standard array keys and they also can have any name since you are accessing them through an array: `$_GET["id-123"]`.

But note your example `www.site.com/id123` implies a PATH_INFO and normally has nothing to do with $_GET or $_POST.

Comment: it does in the sense my htaccess file rewrites that url then uses the rewritten url to access a get variable. See edit above

Comment: OK, so the final answer is: yes, variables can have any name but you have to use a different syntax.

Comment: No, this is not true. PHP accepts it because it doesn't bother checking, but they are _still illegal_. They do still cause problems, too. See the comment by "ianco dot co dot uk" on 28-May-2009 09:47, on [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: They cause problems when you **don't** use variable-variable syntax ($$foo), yes, but he can still use them if he really needs to and it. They only "cause problems" because they are confusing and bad programming style.